# Google Sheets CountIFS

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet that I am trying to count scores of 1 to 5. I can do a `COUNTIF` to count the number of 5s, 4s, 3s, etc.

I need to count the the values separately depending if the value of the first row begins with a space or not. The `COUNTIFS` formula will not work, since the arrays are the same size.

My formulas are:

With space:

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:F1,=" *",B2:F5,"=5")
```

Without space:

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:F1,="<> ",B2:F5,"=5")
```

Here is a sample of my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xmEpTgBKDh-ZuLuxijbqAwx4nRKrThv5LnTI5TgP5XI/edit?usp=sharing

I have several forms and the number of cells that begin with a space varies per sheet and I rather create a formula that works for all of them.

Is there another option I can use other than `COUNTIFS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
=countif(filter(B2:F5, regexmatch(B1:F1, "^\s")), "=4")
```

and see if that works?

And for the header rows that do not start with a space

```
=countif(filter(B2:F5, left(B1:F1, 1)<>" "), "=3")
```